# How to open other user profile in Facebook application using FB scheme

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing application where the user has to provide a facebook link by login to actual an facebook account. Where I am successfully getting link of logged in user.

Reference Link(Edited wrong URL) :

https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/YXNpZX3o4dhgdfhYmZAoZAWlEOGdSNVJuM05xcEdZAcmplelpYaF85bRbFBCSXpNVmJEdsdfgsdgjl1WG0wOEVdsdfhggfhGb0ZA4TZAnRFR0EtZA1ZAJaGtjYnh5YURZATUM4ZIa2V1gdfhdDV1WHhR/

I am able to store it and retrieve to reuse. It is working fine to navigate user under installed application and logged in user profile to same profile. But if I am going to open another registered user with another profile link and added as my contact list. While going to access their actual profile to open under facebook native profile (Edited wrong URL)

https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/WlEOGdSNVJuM05xclelpYaF85bYXNpZX3o4dhgdfhYmZAoZARbFBCSXpNVmJEdsdfgsdgjl1WG0wOEVdsdfhggfhGb0ZA4TZAnEdZAcmpRFR0EtZA1ZAJaGtjYnh5UM4ZIa2V1gdfhdDV1WHhRYURZAT/

I am not able to launch his profile.

To open profile under installed native facebook application I am getting success for:

```
fb://profileapp_scoped_user_id=YXNpZX3o4dhgdfhYmZAoZAWlEOGdSNVJuM05xcEdZAcmplelpYaF85bRbFBCSXpNVmJEdsdfgsdgjl1WG0wOEVdsdfhggfhGb0ZA4TZAnRFR0EtZA1ZAJaGtjYnh5YURZATUM4ZIa2V1gdfhdDV1WHhR/`
```

But not able to redirect to:

```
fb://profile?app_scoped_user_id=WlEOGdSNVJuM05xclelpYaF85bYXNpZX3o4dhgdfhYmZAoZARbFBCSXpNVmJEdsdfgsdgjl1WG0wOEVdsdfhggfhGb0ZA4TZAnEdZAcmpRFR0EtZA1ZAJaGtjYnh5UM4ZIa2V1gdfhdDV1WHhRYURZAT/`
```

Please let me know the appropriate solution.

Comment: @adam-richardson, Thank you for appropriate modification.

Comment: Any other alternative way would also be fine.